# disable options in dropdown in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, javascript

I tried this code to disable the options in the drop-down in the date picker time:

**Script editor:**

[image]

the value is still visible.

[image]

But it is not working.

Kindly advise.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selectId").children("option[value='00']").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Where `#selectID` will be ID of your select control (Add selector carefully to get the particular element only).

**Update**:

For your case try this:

```
$("#Time_x0020_Slot_x0020_Date_b6585aee-0ec0-4964-a13b-67eec8d23e75_$DateTimeFieldDateHours").children("option[value='0']").hide();
```

If you want to remove the option then you need to use this:

```
$("#Time_x0020_Slot_x0020_Date_b6585aee-0ec0-4964-a13b-67eec8d23e75_$DateTimeFieldDateHours").children("option[value='0']").remove();
```

**Note**: Remember, this select element is for Hours drop-down and its option values are like `0, 1, 2...` and so on.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but still is not working. Kindly refer to the screenshots above. This is the html code for that element : <select id="Time_x0020_Slot_x0020_Date_b6585aee-0ec0-4964-a13b-67eec8d23e75_$DateTimeFieldDateHours"><option value="0">00:</option><option value="1">01:</option><option value="2">02:</option><option value="3">03:</option><option value="4">04:</option><option value="5">05:</option><option value="6">06:</option><option value="7">07:</option></select>

Comment: Use selector as `$("#selectID")`. you are missing `#` in your selector.

Comment: See updated answer. This is for hours dropdown and not for minutes dropdown.

Comment: I did like u said but it is still not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any error in browser's console?

Comment: nope, there's no errors. fyi i am using IE. I read online some codes does not work for IE. Not sure if that helps

Comment: Try adding `.remove()` instead of `.hide()`.

Comment: still in vain :( do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try adding debugger, I guess you are not getting the right select dropdown using the selector.

Comment: This is what is in the debugger:<nobr>Time Slot Date</nobr>
</span></td>
<td valign="top" width="350px" class="ms-formbody">
<!-- FieldName="Time Slot Date"
FieldInternalName="Time_x0020_Slot_x0020_Date"
 FieldType="SPFieldDateTime"
   -->
  <span id='WPQ2d5c1dd8d-77cc-40aa-a252-4c088c065422Time_x0020_Slot_x0020_Date' data-sp-control='SPFieldDateTime' data-sp-options='{&quot;mode&quot;:3,&quot;source&quot;:&quot;Time_x0020_Slot_x0020_Date&quot;}'></span>

Comment: Add debugger inside document.ready() and Check what are you getting in `$("#Time_x0020_Slot_x0020_Date_b6585aee-0ec0-4964-a13b-67eec8d23e75_$DateTimeFieldDateHours")`. Are you getting the select element object?

Comment: Nope. I put it in the script editor and nothing happened.

Comment: Oh i tried again and it says 'cannot read property children'

Comment: Are you getting the select element object using selector? because the issue is with your selector.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error. Kindly refer to the last 2 images in the question

Comment: The code seems to run (code in your updated answer e.g. children("option[value='0']".hide) Now the console has no errors and both the console user messages are shown. But the option value is still there. I even tried removing instead. How can I go from here

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code: This is example to disable first value(0th position) in dropdown.

Here "DT" in the jQuery selector(`$("input[title='DT']")`) is the "title" of DateTime field. (Update this with the title of you field). No Need to update anything else. It should work.

```
var tdTimeSection = $("input[title='DT']").closest("td").siblings(".ms-dttimeinput");
$(tdTimeSection).find("select:eq(0)").find("option[value='0']").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

[image]

Comment: I tried like you said (changed the DT)but I still see the value. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? If yes, please share the details

Comment: There is no errors in the console. I used console logs front n back to verify the code ran. But the value is still visible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am just ignorant, but why not just change the Time Slot Date column to only be a **Date Field** and not a **Date and Time field**?

Maybe try this if you must use jQuery:

```
$("select[id*='Time']").hide();
```

**If that wont work** - you may have better luck by putting the script in a .html file and store it on the site and refer to it with a content editor web part. Sometimes the Snippets do funny things.

Comment: I need the item too, but only certain values

Comment: The original post needs to be a little bit more specific then, what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?